# Odoo 10 - debug issue with mail template in sales order

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am getting this error when trying to send an email in sales order (quote).

When I dismiss the error message I get the modal window for sending email but no template has been selected and I have to select it manually. Then everything works fine

I hence suspect that the issue is that for some reason it is not getting the default template.

Any tips on how to fix this?

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 885, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5491, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5389, in _onchange_eval
    method_res = method(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 342, in onchange_template_id_wrapper
    values = self.onchange_template_id(self.template_id.id, self.composition_mode, self.model, self.res_id)['value']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 364, in onchange_template_id
    values = self.generate_email_for_composer(template_id, [res_id])[res_id]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 501, in generate_email_for_composer
    template_values = self.env['mail.template'].with_context(tpl_partners_only=True).browse(template_id).generate_email(res_ids, fields=fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 482, in generate_email
    res_ids_to_templates = self.get_email_template(res_ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 423, in get_email_template
    langs = self.render_template(self.lang, self.model, res_ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 380, in render_template
    records = self.env[model].browse(filter(None, res_ids))  # filter to avoid browsing [None]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 760, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 174, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: False
```

Comment: My first guess, is that the model on the default template is wrong. Would be interesting which template is loaded and what model it's set for.

Comment: How can I check which is the default template? And once I know the default template, how can I check which model is for that template?

Comment: In an default Odoo installation, there is one template for model `sale.order` which will be used when clicking on "Send by Email": It's called "Sales Order - Send by Email". Have you changed something from default installation? If yes, what (related to sales orders and email templates)?

Comment: I have 5 different custom email templates for sale.order, properly configured. But when I click "Send by email" it seems that it is not selecting anyone by default. Where do I check which template "Send by email" selects by default?

Comment: I think it's directly in the code. Odoo has external references (xml ids) for this, so it's possible to change it deep in the backend, but i guess you already have your answer :-)

Comment: It can be changed via settings menu (as stated in the check link in the answer). The problem was that I duplicated the template, modified it and finally deleted the original one.

Comment: Yep, already read it. Deleting non demo data (unit of measures, products, templates, parameters, etc.) can always bring up problems. Only delete such things, if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:

[Odoo Support forum - Change Default Mail Template](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/change-default-mail-template-for-quote-order-37281)

I changed the template (duplicate and deleted the original one) so you have to change the ID which refers to old one.